# Sharing run configurations in JetBrains Rider

Tags: jetbrains-ide, rider

Our team is now trying Rider and we quite like it. We would like to setup some run configurations to run projects and some associated tasks with them (such as running `grunt` prebuild).

When I setup the configurations, mark them all as "Share through VCS" and add them to git, after restarting Rider the configurations are not loaded. We have ignored everything in `.idea/**` folder in our `.gitignore`, except these run configurations in `runConfigurations` folder.

Is it a problem with `.gitignore` setup? Or is there some special setting we have to use in order to force Rider to load these configurations?

Comment: Looks like a bug. Even if something's wrong with your `.gitignore`, the configurations should still load on the same machine. Could you please report this issue to Rider support or to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/RIDER ?

Comment: I sent similar question to Rider support. I have managed to save some configurations by combination of create configuration -> commit -> close solution -> close rider. Then about every third configuration gets saved and loaded properly, even on other computers. If I have some time I will submit it also to YouTrack with some reproducible sample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rider 2019.3.2 saves run configurations as XML files with UTF-8 with BOM encoding. When you change the encoding manually to UTF-8 (without BOM) it starts working and the configurations are loaded as expected.